# How to dispose an object only when an exception was raised?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, dispose

I instantiate a disposable object (in my case a FileStream) in my constructor and need to do some work on it. However, this might throw any number of different exceptions. Now I don't even want to mess with these exceptions too much and want to allow them to propagate up to the caller. However, I need to dispose the object first. Now what's the best way to do that? Right now I can only think of something like that:

```
IDisposable disposableObject = InstantiateDisposable();
bool error = false;
try
{
    DoWork(disposableObject);
}
catch (ReallyBadException e)
{
    error = true;
    throw new EvenWorseException("some message", e);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    error = true;
    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (error) disposableObject.Dispose();
}
```

Is that even correct or will the Dispose() be skipped in some special cases? Is there an easier way to do that? It gets a bit cumbersome, if you need to catch a bunch of different exceptions seperately for whatever reason and you always have to copy & paste that `error = true;` bit.

**Edit:** 
Just to clarify: I only need to dispose the object in case of `DoWork()` failing / throwing an exception. If this method succeeds, I don't want to dispose the object just yet, as there'll be more work to do with it later on.

Comment: Why don't you just do *all* the work inside a using block?

Comment: I can't, because I'll need to use the disposable object frequently over a relatively long time period. For that reason I intend to keep it alive as long as the "parent" object holding a reference to it is kept alive.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Maybe you should edit the question to make that requirement explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not invert the logic?

```
IDisposable disposableObject = InstantiateDisposable();
bool error = true;
try
{
    DoWork(disposableObject);
    error = false; // if it gets to this line, no exception was thrown
}
catch (ReallyBadException e)
{        
    throw new EvenWorseException("some message", e);
}    
finally
{
    if (error) disposableObject.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Ah, that's so obvious... I feel somewhat stupid now. It's still a lot of boiler-plate code, though.

Comment: @Mario the `catch(Exception)` can be removed entirely in this case, at least. I'll edit to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and "handle" exceptions you can't actually do anything about.

Unless you've got some clear usefulness from logging a diagnostic, or re-throwing as a different type, just let it fail & release 'disposableObject' in a 'finally' clause!

Many people get too confused, or do pointless mick-muckery, when it comes to exception handling. You should get a trace when it comes out at the bottom. No point in 'catch & immediately re-throw'.

```
IDisposable disposableObject = InstantiateDisposable();
bool error = true;
try {
    DoWork(disposableObject);
    error = false; // if it gets to this line, no exception was thrown

} finally {
    if (error) disposableObject.Dispose();
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it just me, or is `finally { if (error) dispose(); }` serving the exact same purpose as `catch (Exception) { dispose(); throw; }`?  You could get rid of the condition altogether, and you don't need a `finally` block unless you have code that must *always* run.

Comment: @cHao In this code sample, yeah.  But the question does some exception-specific work that this answer omits.

Comment: @Paul: That's the whole point of the answer -- that that exception-specific work *should* be omitted.  With that gone, there's nothing in the way of catching `Exception` and doing cleanup that *should only happen if an exception is thrown*, rather than abusing `finally` as an exception handler.

Comment: @cHao Wrapping a "native" exception with one specific to your application is a pretty good practice.  I think it's a more than acceptable reason to include a specific `catch`.

Comment: @Paul: Tell that to Thomas.  It's his answer; i'm just running with his idea.  :)

Comment: In Java we've moved away from that. Much complexity & potential error hides in 'catch' blocks..  I can't count how many erroneous 'catch & silently ignore', 'catch & not release resource', 'catch and throw without original cause' examples I've had to fix in the goal of high-reliability code.

Comment: Normally, we'd only wrap an Exception as something else when moving between domain layers -- eg, between persistence library and application, or between business logic & presentation tier when separated by CORBA/ RPC.

Answer (score 2):

```
IDisposable disposable = InstantiateDisposable();
try
{
    try
    {
        DoWork(disposable);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
        throw;
    }
}
catch (ReallyBadException ex)
{
    throw new EvenWorseException("some message", ex);
}
```

Although, really, unless you are returning the object or squirreling it away for something, you should use a `using` block and always dispose it.

Comment: doesn't this wrap every type of exception in an `EvenWorseException`?  So the caller must always inspect the inner exception to determine what type of exception was really thrown?

Comment: @adrift: Nope.  It only wraps `ReallyBadException`s in an `EvenWorseException`.   Other exceptions will propagate as is.

Comment: One problem with this approach is that it will cause all `finally` methods between the `throw` and your code to execute, before the system can determine whether the exception will be caught.  If one isn't going to resolve an exception, it's generally better not to catch it than to unconditionally catch and rethrow.

Comment: @supercat: The `finally` code will run either way; each try/catch's `finally` block runs once control leaves it, whether it completed successfully or threw an exception.  Unless you're saying something different than you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Why not `Dispose` in the `catch`?

```
IDisposable disposableObject = InstantiateDisposable();

try
{
    DoWork(disposableObject);
}
catch (ReallyBadException e)
{
    disposableObject.Dispose();
    throw new EvenWorseException("some message", e);
}
catch (Exception)
{
    disposableObject.Dispose();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Biggest reason for not disposing in the catch blocks is, you're repeating yourself.  You don't want to have to remember to dispose the object through every possible error path, cause it's all but guaranteed you'll eventually miss one.

Comment: @cHao: True but if you are going to be adding a boolean to indicate when in the `finally` you are going actually dispose its really no more work either way. Now you need to flag in every catch to dispose the object, why not just dispose there? You make this point in your comment on Thomas W.'s answer.

Comment: @tkeE2036: Exactly the reason i haven't upvoted any answers that involve a flag.  :)  See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719403/how-to-dispose-an-object-only-when-an-exception-was-raised/7719514#7719514) for a more foolproof way.  Although inverting the logic does drastically reduce the error-proneness of using a flag...at that point, you only set it if everything went OK, rather than every time an error happens.  If you keep the number of exit points down, or do all your bailing before you reach the point of needing cleanup, then that's one setting of the flag.

Comment: @cHao, for me at least, KISS outweighs DRY in this particular example.  If the code ever changed to become more complex, I would consider refactoring.  But really, it's only 1 line being repeated.

Comment: @adrift: It often starts out as "only 1 line", and before you know it you have a big bowl of copypasta.  Better to not even start down that road, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping within a utility object like this?

```csharp
class Disposer : IDisposable
{
    private IDisposable target;

    public Disposer(IDisposable target)
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void Cancel()
    {
        this.target = null;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.target?.Dispose();
        Cancel();
    }
}
```

This is equivalent to managing `bool error` flag, but arguably a bit cleaner if you like `using`:

```csharp
IDisposable disposableObject = InstantiateDisposable();
using (Disposer disposer = new Disposer(disposableObject))
{
    try
    {
        DoWork(disposableObject);
        disposer.Cancel();
    }
    catch (ReallyBadException e)
    {
        throw new EvenWorseException("some message", e);
    }
}

// ... continue with disposableObject
```

Answer (score -1):

Is there a reason why you're not disposing the object when there's no error? You probably should be!

Using the standard [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) pattern means that your object will always be safely disposed, and then you only need to worry about catching any exceptions -- eg, `ReallyBadException` -- which need special attention. Any other exceptions will bubble up to the caller.

```
using (IDisposable disposableObject = InstantiateDisposable())
{
    try
    {
        DoWork(disposableObject);
    }
    catch (ReallyBadException e)
    {
        throw new EvenWorseException("some message", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: (not my DV) aside the fact that the OP does not want to dispose the object unless there's an exception, isn't throwing exception from a using block kinda useless. Don't using blocks swallow exceptions, per se?

Comment: @Bala: A `using` block creates a `finally`, not a `catch`, so exceptions aren't swallowed.

Comment: Right, I only need to dispose right there, if there's some kind of error. If `DoWork()` actually succeeds without exception, I'll store a reference to the disposable object for later use. Of course it'll be disposed eventually at some point in the future - just not right there.

Comment: @BalaR: That's just an artifact of throwing an exception from a `finally` block. The OP's code has the same "problem", assuming that the `Dispose` call he's making can throw in the first place.

Comment: @BalaR: If one writes a wrapper in vb, one can test whether an object implements `IDisposableEx` with method `Dispose(Exception ex)` and call that method with either `null` (if there was no exception) or else the pending exception (if there was one).  Note that the wrapper, if written in vb, will *not* have to catch and rethrow the exception, but can simply avoid catching it in the first place.  It's too bad that pattern wasn't built into the framework, since in many cases a `using` block that's exited via exception should be handled differently from one which isn't.  For example...

Comment: ...it may be useful to design a reader/writer lock token so that if a writer exits its `using` block normally, it will release the lock and allow other code to enter, but if it exits via an exception it will invalidate the lock so any pending or future attempts to acquire it will throw exceptions.  As Eric Lippert points out, simply releasing the lock in such case may be dangerous, but leaving all other processes deadlocked is pretty horrible as well.  Having attempts to use the potentially-corrupted object throw exceptions is the best course, but there's no nice `using`ish syntax.